# convert to binary file

Tags: c, file, binaryfiles

I need to convert a text file of the following format to binary file.
The input file only contains characters A, B, C or D. 'A' changes to '00','B' changes to '01', C changes to '10', D changes to '11'. 
Sample input file:

```
ABBCDA
BBAABCD
BACBB
```

Sample output file:

```
000101101100
01010000011011
0100100101
```

I have wrote the following code, but it doesn't work.

```
int main()
{
    FILE * fop;
    FILE * fout;
    int length=0;
    int i;
    char buffer[1000];
    fop = fopen("filename.txt","r");
    fout = fopen("filename.bin", "wb");
    while(!feof(fop))
    {
        fgets(buffer,1000,fop);
        length = strlen(buffer)-1;
        for(i=0; i<length; i++)
         {
           if(buffer[i]=='A')
           strcpy(buffer[i],'00');
           if(buffer[i]=='B')
           strcpy(buffer[i],'01');
           if(buffer[i]=='C')
           strcpy(buffer[i],'10');
           if(buffer[i]=='D')
           strcpy(buffer[i],'11'); 
         }
      fwrite(buffer, 1, sizeof(char)*length, fout);
      fwrite("\n",1,sizeof(char),fout);
    }
    fclose(fop);
    fclose(fout);
    return 0;
}
```

What's wrong? How to solve it? Thank you.

Comment: Copying **two characters**? You have two problems now!

Comment: 1. Please check the return values from `fopen`. 2 Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) about the use of `feof`. 3. Check the return value from `fgets` ...

Comment: You should also compile will all the warnings on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the part to be fixed

```
while(fgets(buffer,1000,fop))
{
    length = strlen(buffer)-1;
    char sout[3];
    for(i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        *sout = '\0';
        if(buffer[i]=='A')
            strcpy(sout,"00");
        if(buffer[i]=='B')
            strcpy(sout,"01");
        if(buffer[i]=='C')
            strcpy(sout,"10");
        if(buffer[i]=='D')
            strcpy(sout,"11"); 
        fwrite(sout, 1, strlen(sout), fout);
    }
    fwrite("\n",1,sizeof(char),fout);
}
```

Notes

- the `fgets` within the `while` condition
- `sout` to store temporarily the 2-bits (as string)
- `fwrite` writes to `sout` (does not overwrite buffer), and is integrated within the for loop while the writing of `\n` is outside.

---

Version to write actual bytes (in binary) ...

```
while(fgets(buffer,1000,fop))
{
    length = strlen(buffer)-1;
    for(i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        unsigned char byte = 0;
        if(buffer[i]=='A')
            byte = 0x0;
        if(buffer[i]=='B')
            byte = 0x1;
        if(buffer[i]=='C')
            byte = 0x2;
        if(buffer[i]=='D')
            byte = 0x3; 
        fwrite(&byte, 1, 1, fout);
    }
    // no more : fwrite("\n",1,sizeof(char),fout);
}
```

Using `0x` notation to show I'm dealing with binary stuff...

And version David C. Rankin (perfectionist!)

```
while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fop)) {    /* read each line */
    char *p = buf;                  /* pointer to buf */
    while (*p) {                    /* while not '\0' */
        uint8_t byte = 0;           /* declare byte */
        if ('A' <= *p && *p <= 'Z') /* if char is A-Z */
            byte = *p - 'A';        /* encode 0 - 25 */
        else
            byte = *p;              /* write char as is */
        if (fwrite (&byte, 1, 1, fout) != 1) {   /* validate write */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: write of '%c' failed.\n", *p);
            goto badwrite;          /* jump out of loops on fail */
        }
        p++;    /* increment pointer */
    }
}
badwrite:;

fclose (fop);                /* close input file */
if (fclose (fout) == -1)     /* close/validate output file */
    fprintf (stderr, "error: on fout close.\n");
```

There is yet some stuff that can be improved, but for now ...

Comment: `char sout[2];` -> `char sout[3];`

Comment: Are you sure `char sout[2]` won't run into problems?

Comment: `fwrite("\n",1,sizeof(char),fout);` - Would `fputc` be a better  choice

Comment: Also a `switch` statement might be better than all those `ifs`

Comment: I'm still confused. if `'A'` is supposed to be **zero**, `'B'` is supposed to be `1`, `'C'` is supposed to be `2`... (each being a (byte) -- "Why are we not writing `uint8_t` to the file?"

Comment: @yoyoyoyo11  [3] is the number of characters in sout, 2 for the text version of the binary byte (00, 01 ...), one for the trailing `\0`

Comment: Only thing I would do different is walk down each line with `uint8_t byte = *p - 'A';` and then validate the close of the output file `if (fclose (fout) == -1)` to catch any stream error on close (you don't care about the input file, but the output file close is worth checking)

Comment: @David indeed again. Added your version! However TBH, the code I write here on SO tries to stick more to OP's code (otherwise they might seem lost). But you definitely have the touch!

Comment: The only other thing that really ought to be done if we are encoding the character file to a binary file with `'A-Z'` encoded `0-25` is we should also write the `newline`. (and that is my fault for not catching it sooner). That is required to allow the binary file to be decoded to exactly what the original was. So I would add/change to `char *p = buf; while (*p) { uint8_t byte = 0; if ('A' <= *p && *p <= 'Z') byte = *p - 'A'; else byte = *p; if (fwrite (&byte, 1, 1, fout) != 1) { /* handle error */} p++; }` Then you can get back exactly what you put in `:)`

Comment: I took the liberty to change that part in your answer `:)`

Comment: @David it's partly yours now ;-)

Comment: I'm happy to share. Once I get my last cat in the house (to insure it's not fox-bait -- which produces really unhappy kids in the morning) I'm letting the turkey win and closing my eyes `:)`